# How to get the Id of parent ancher tag of custom action?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-designer

using Jquery am trying to get the id of parent ancher tag of custom Action(Ribbon) in sharepoint but am unable to get it.
My HTML is as like

```
    <a unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="ms-cui-ctl-large " mscui:controltype="Button" role="button" id="{E549A47E-BA3E-4D2B-A496-5B9C077A875F}-Large">
    <span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer">
    <span unselectable="on" class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float"></span>
    </span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel">Custom Action<br></span>
   </a>
```

and this is the script am aplying to get the Id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    var ttle=$("input[title='custom Action']")[0].parent().attr('id');
    alert(ttle);
     });                                                                                            
</script>
```

here is snap of screen
 
[image]
but it is not working.
is there any solution for that?

Comment: Post HTML in this case!

Comment: You can try this, `$("input[title='custom Action']").parent().attr('id')`

Comment: Can you please add a sample code?

Comment: @ Aruna i tried the approach you told that shows me ubdefine

Answer (score 0):

this "`$("input[title='custom Action']")[0]`" is a dom object!
cover it with another $ sign and it would work!

```
var ttle=$($("input[title='custom Action']")[0]).parent().attr('id');
alert(ttle);
```

Comment: That does not make sense at all. Just replacing the [0] would be the answer to get a Jquery Object.